# consul - Duplicate call generated during timeout

Tags: spring, consul, spring-cloud-consul

I have two micro services MS1 and MS2 running on 2 nodes say n1 and n2. When MS1 calls MS2, consul discovers MS2 of node1. However, MS2 of node1 takes longer than the read timeout defined. As soon as the timeout is reached, I see a call coming to MS2 of node2.

Is this the expected behavior of Consul to redirect a call to a different node when the 1st node takes long?

This is happening only if the endpoint is a GET Request, does not happen in  a POST request.

Comment: Are you using Consul service mesh, or just the basic Spring Cloud integration? A proxy sidecar in the service mesh could retry the request automatically, if it has been configured to do so.

Comment: Dont know what is service mesh. I think what we have is Spring cloud integration. Also, this duplicay happens only if the endpoint is a GET request, not in a POST request.